# Creating Stream DATABASE in a remote server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, streaming

Whith the assistance of a very good fellow from this forum (Mr. DJHnz) i solve my first issue regarding the creation of a stream database
Now i'm facing another issue 
I'm giving you the code:

---

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_AddStreamDB]    Script Date: 12/21/2009 09:55:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AddStreamDB](
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @DPath varchar(MAX),
    @DBName varchar(50),
    @Qchar varchar(1) = "'"
) AS
BEGIN_TRY:
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here 
    DECLARE
    @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000),
    @DBName1 varchar(50),
    @DBName2 varchar(50),
    @DBNamefs varchar(50),
    @DBNamelog varchar(50),
    @FileGroupN varchar(100),
    @DATName varchar(MAX),
    @LOGName varchar(MAX),
    @FSName varchar(MAX),
    @CreateSdb nvarchar(MAX),
    @Statement nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @DBName1 = (@DBName + '1')
    SET @DBName2 = (@DBName + '2')
    SET @DBNamefs = (@DBName + 'fs')
    SET @DBNamelog = (@DBName + 'log')
    SET @FileGroupN = (@DBname + 'StreamGroup')
    SET @DATName = (@Qchar + @DPath + @DBName +'_dat.mdf' + @Qchar)
    SET @LOGName = (@Qchar + @DPath + @DBName +'_log.ldf' + @Qchar)
    SET @FSName =  (@Qchar + @DPath + @DBName + '_fs' + @Qchar)
SET @CreateSdb =('CREATE DATABASE ' + @DBName + ' ON PRIMARY (NAME = ' + @DBName1 + ', FILENAME = ' + @DATName + '), FILEGROUP ' + @FileGroupN + ' CONTAINS FILESTREAM (NAME = ' + @DBNamefs + ', FILENAME = ' + @FSName + ') LOG ON (NAME = ' + @DBNamelog + ', FILENAME = ' + @LOGName + ')')
    SET @Statement = '   '
BEGIN_CATCH:
SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;
SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()

EXEC master.sys.sp_executesql @CreateSdb, @Statement

RAISERROR (@ErrMsg,1,1)
RETURN 0 
END_CATCH:
END_TRY:
```

---

So far to point everything works fine until the remote server tries to create the neccessary files for the stream DB

### then he gives the following error:

Unable to open the physical file "C:\sqlDATA\RemoteDB_fs". Operating system error -2147024891: "0x80070005(Access is denied.)".

---

The name of the drive C:\ lies on the remote machine (a machine near to me in the same network with Windows server 2003; later i will run the program for my ISP machine)
the subfolder sqlDATA\ is already there i have created manually as it should be.
In my local machine the all package works fine and the DATA BASE created fine but the issue starts when i use remote server.

NOW I NEED THE HELP:

## Why i receive this ERROR?

Comment: format your code please for readability

Comment: Sorry but as far as i see the code is very well readable

Comment: @lefteris: because I formatted it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Server service account does not have rights on C:\SQLData

Comment: The account is the 'sa' and this account has all the rights also i have another account 'Administrator' and i'm using it and gives me the same error
But now i'm thinging please give me few seconds to try the account DOMAIN\Administrator

Comment: Only the domain account running the SQL Server service matters. "sa" will not have file system rights, nor will any other login via SQL Server. It's separate to internal SQL Server permissions

Comment: Sorry for my delay, I use the account of build in Administrator with ServerRole DiskAdmin and dbcreator and securityadmin and serveradmin but nothing
i receive the same error:
Unable to open the physical file "C:\sqlDATA\RemoteDB_fs". Operating system error -2147024891: "0x80070005(Access is denied.)".
==

Comment: The 'sa' account is not diskadmin server role

Comment: "sa" is every role. Like I said, it's the service account permissions that matter. Not the login used to connect to SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

As @gbn explained and also:

- `C:\sqlDATA`  directory **must** exist.
- The `\RemoteDB_fs` sub-directory for file-stream **must not** exist.

Comment: Yes that is right 
the C:\sqlDATA\ exists and the RemoteDB_fs not exist
i know that because it is elementary for stream Data Base creation
but i receive the same error
and with other sql accounts where i have create